# WordPress - Trouble with enqueue-ing scripts/CSS

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, wordpress

So, I've not used Wordpress in a long time, and I'm trying to get back into the swing of things.  Apparently the correct way to deal with external CSS/JS is to enqueue them using `wp_register_style`, `wp_enqueue_style`, `wp_register_script`, and `wp_enqueue_script`... but they're not working for me at all.

The following is my current `functions.php`:

```
<?php

    // Enqueue necessary scripts/etc.
    function wasd_styles() {
        wp_register_style('semantic-css', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/lib/semantic.min.css');
        wp_enqueue_style('semantic-css');
    }

    function wasd_scripts() {
        wp_register_script('semantic-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/lib/semantic.min.js');
        wp_enqueue_script('semantic-js');
    }

    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wasd_styles');
    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wasd_scripts');

?>
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong?  As far as I can tell, it should be injecting the proper calls to grab CSS/JS into the  tag of my page, but..it's not.

The following are the two files I'm attempting to render, I threw this together in like 5 minutes to attempt to test Semantic UI, but it's just not working at all, no style is being rendered, and  is empty upon source inspection.

**index.php**

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<div class="ui main container">
    <h2 class="ui dividing header">This is a test</h2>
</div>
```

**header.php**

```
<div class="ui top fixed inverted menu">
    <div class="item">Test</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the code you have shared, your theme does not support the use of `wp_enqueue_script()`. This function simply registers the scripts and gets it ready for insertion into the DOM. This is inserted via a hook, which doesn't appear to be present in your theme. You would need to add the following into your `header.php` file. This would typically be added between the `<head></head>` tags.

`<?php wp_head(); ?>`

Also, you should have a similar hook in your `footer.php` file, typically just before the closing `</body>` tag. This hook would be:

`<?php wp_footer(); ?>`

Without these, `wp_enqueue_script()` and `wp_enqueue_style()` will not work.

Comment: Since I posted my self-answer at the same time you posted this, I'll accept yours as the answer, because it was indeed my problem.  I'm pretty new to WP, and just overlooked it.   Thank you very much for your quick response.

Comment: Thanks. Happy coding!